# Как откатиться до определенного коммита? (много гуглил не могу найти ответа)

Tags: git

Я уже два дня гуглю и нахожу кучу запутанных и непонятных ответов, хотя вопрос простой, гит это система сейв лоад как в играх, я делал много сейвов, коммитов, хочу сделать лоад определенного, это как в игре загрузить определенный сейв. Как это сделать? Если мой вопрос знатоки гита могут понять по разному, то дайте пожалуйста любой вариант на ваш вкус. Я делал штуки, штуки плохие, помню что сейвился где штуки были хорошие, хочу загрузиться до того состояния и играть дальше. Это же базовый функционал для которого создан гит. Я и правда не могу найти ни одного нормального обьяснения.

должна же быть команда типа такой:

```
git reset #fgfgfg
```

неужели такого не сделали?

а так же нужно это всё выгрузить на github, хотя при git push система пишет что новых коммитов нет и выгружать нечего, а при попытке создат новый коммит система пишет что новых файлов не обнаружено(

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127003/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас по сути 2 задачи:

- откатить ветку в прошлое
- отправить это изменение на удаленный репозиторий

Для отката ветки в прошлое есть команда [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). У нее есть разные опции, ваша скорее всего `--hard`

Важно понимать, что при такой операции последние коммиты могут быть потеряны. То есть вы откатываетесь в прошлое и это может быть билетом в один конец.

Для отправки подобного ижменения в удаленный репозиторий, используется команда [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). По умолчанию она не позволяет обновлять ветки, откатанные в прошлое. Чтобы это заработало вы можете форсировать отправку параметром `--force`.

Подобная практика приемлема, если вы один работаете над репозиторием. В командной работе ручная откатка коммита не только может привести к потере истории, но и может стать головной болью ваших коллег по команде.

Чтобы в будущем иметь меньше проблем с git, рекомедую использовать какую либо [стратегию версионирования](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows), тот же `git feature branching` или `gitflow` позволяют вам работать в своей ветке и делать в ней всё, что необходимо, без влияния на коллег.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз один работаю над проектом, и использую AWS CD/CI конвеер, от сюда и git)

Answer (score 1):

Если ситуация такая:

Commit#1 -> Commit#2 -> !!BadCommit!! -> Commit#3 -> Commit#4

И все это уже отправлено в удаленный репозиторий, то используйте команду [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

```
git revert !!BadCommit!!
git push
```

Comment: Тут надо отметить что `git revert` создаст еще один коммит, с изменениями, противоположными тем что были в !!BadCommit!!.

Comment: Ага, это позволяет сохранить историю изменений.

Comment: git revert делает вообще какую то дичь с файлами,  а старые файлы не восстанавливаются да и еще какие то странные появляются со всякими стрелочками >>>>>>>>>>

Comment: @Иван Вольнов, это не конкретно git revert такое делает, а просто при слиянии изменений и текущей версии файлов возникли неоднозначности, которые нужно разрешать вручную. Не повезло короче. Стрелочками отмечены места, которые нужно вручную править.

Answer (score 0):

Вот способ без потери истории.

```
git checkout <commit-id-к-которому-хотите-вернуться> -- .
```

Эта команда вернет все локальные файлы в состояние, какое у них было в комите (в том числе восстановит удаленные файлы и т.д.), но при этом не трогает историю. Т.е. эти изменения нужно теперь закомитить. И дальше делать обычный push.

Если скажем есть история:

```
5eec1a5 (HEAD -> master) deletes g
9bd439a deletes f
fdd34b3 adds g. I want to revert here. I have f and g at this time
92819dd initial. adds f
```

Тогда команды:

```
git checkout fdd34b3 -- .
git commit -m "revert deletes"
```

создадут такую историю:

```
fcf9a36 (HEAD -> master) revert deletes
5eec1a5 deletes g
9bd439a deletes f
fdd34b3 adds g. I want to revert here. I have f and g at this time
92819dd initial. adds f
```

И состояние файлов в `fcf9a36` и `fdd34b3` будет идентичным.

Это откат состояния, путем создания нового изменения, которое приводит состояние файлов в такое, какое было в том старом комите. Все существующие до этого комиты сохраняются. Т.е. все комиты останутся в истории, и создастся новый, в котором удаленные файлы будут заново добавлены.

Comment: Как это без потери истории? Откатившись на коммит, изменив в нем файлы и запушив - что будет с теми коммитами что после этого коммита?

Comment: Коммиты до этого сохраняются, а коммиты после этого? с ними что?

Comment: И все будет не так, как вы пишете. Это не будет "изменение файлов в комите". Это будет создание нового комита, с изменениями противоположными тем, какие были сделаны в комитах после того старого.

Comment: Нет никаких комитов после. Это все происходит на последнем комите из ветки.

Comment: Фактически коммит в detached head создаст новую ветку от коммита.

Comment: Тут нет никакого detached head. Вы путаете команды `git checkout <commit>` и `git checkout <commit> -- <path>`. Они работают по разному